# Parallel Computing with MEX files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, fortran, mex, parfor

Is it possible to run a MEX file in parallel using Parallel Computing Toolbox in Matlab (parfor)?
I compiled a Fortran application to a MEX file using gfortran compiler. It works without problems:

```
mass=getMass(x);
```

But when I try to run it parallel, it crashes. Fe.:

```
matlabpool 4
parfor i=1:80
    mass(i)=getMass(x);
end
```

I get the following error:

> Error using **distcomp.remoteparfor/getCompleteIntervals** (line 22)
>   The session that parfor is using has shut down.
>
> Caused by:
>       Error using **distcomp.remoteparfor/getCompleteIntervals** (line 22)
>       The session that parfor is using has shut down.
>
> The client lost connection to lab 3. This might be due to network problems, or
>   the interactive matlabpool job might have errored.

Other functions (not MEX) run without problems in parallel. I am using Matlab R2013a on OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: How does the code for getMass look like? It may not be thread safe. See, e.g., https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/270572

Comment: It's quite complex Fortran program. Maybe the problem is with IO? Since it writes some unformatted data to the hard disc each time:

OPEN( UNIT = 3, FORM = "UNFORMATTED", ACCESS = "SEQUENTIAL" )

Comment: It can be anything. IO, or saved variables, who knows. Try to do some debugging. Try declaring the subroutine `recursive`.

Comment: I don't know, if your actual problem allows this, but I would try to create parallelisation via OpenMP in Fortran.

Comment: The PCT pool workers are in separate processes, not threads. They have separate memory spaces and Matlab sessions, but share the filesystem. Prob not thread safety per se. If the Fortran code is doing I/O, and not expecting to have multiple copies running at the same time on the same box, you may have file name collisions and reader/writer contention on the files. Maybe you could have each process work in a separate directory or include the PID in their filenames? Plus, see if you can get it to produce a log file so you can get an error message indicating the cause of the worker shutdown.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is with Fortran application I/O. I copied MEX file to the other directory and it runs very well in additional instance of Matlab. Is it possible to fix this problem to use Parallel Computing toolbox? Probably I would have to use unique number for unit each time when I write to the file in Fortran. Yet I have no idea how to do it. I would like to use parallel computing with genetic algorithm and do a little comparison for my thesis. Otherwise, running it in separate instances of Matlab would have been more than enough.

Comment: See my answer. Obviously, if the error is not in the unit number, it will not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use new unit number for every `open`. Be sure to also avoid writing to the same file from more threads, but from what you presented it seems you have just scratch files and they should be OK, they are distinguished by the unit number.

If your compiler supports `newunit` specifier from Fortran 2008 it is very easy:

```
integer :: u
open(newunit=u, form=...

write(u,fmt) the_variables

close(u)
```

It automatically assigns a unit number, that is not used and is not in clash with any hardwired unit number, because it is negative.

It is also possible to write a function, that finds some free unit using `inquire`, but you must not call such a function from more threads at the same time.

```
  subroutine newunit(unit)
     integer,intent(out) :: unit
     logical :: isOpen

     integer, parameter :: MIN_UNIT_NUMBER = 10
     integer, parameter :: MAX_UNIT_NUMBER = 99

     do unit = MIN_UNIT_NUMBER, MAX_UNIT_NUMBER
        inquire(unit = unit, opened = isOpen)
        if (.not. isOpen) then
           return
        end if
     end do

     unit = -1
  end subroutine newunit
```

More advanced versions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your mex function must be thread safe. If parts of it are not thread safe, e.g. IO operations to a single file, writes to shared memory etc., then these parts need to be protected with a mutex.